# MS Access Report Groups on Sort Fields

Tags: sorting, ms-access, reporting

I'm trying to create a report (an invoice, actually) in Access that sorts by one field, then groups by another.  However, Access is also creating a group footer section whenever the *sort* field changes.  I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is by design.

In the example below I want to group on "Group" but first sort by UnitPrice.  This is what I want it to look like:

```
    Product                              Unit Price         Group
    -------                              ----------         -----
    Product 1                                  0.70         Group 1
    Product 2                                  0.71         Group 1
    Product 3                                  0.72         Group 1

    --- Group Footer ---

    Product 4                                  0.80         Group 2
    Product 5                                  0.80         Group 2

    --- Group Footer ---

    Product 6                                  0.98         Group 1
    Product 7                                  0.98         Group 1
    Product 8                                  0.98         Group 1

    --- Group Footer ---
```

but what I'm getting is this:

```
    Product                              Unit Price         Group
    -------                              ----------         -----
    Product 1                                  0.70         Group 1

    --- Group Footer ---

    Product 2                                  0.71         Group 1

    --- Group Footer ---

    Product 3                                  0.72         Group 1

    --- Group Footer ---

    Product 4                                  0.80         Group 2
    Product 5                                  0.80         Group 2

    --- Group Footer ---

    Product 6                                  0.98         Group 1
    Product 7                                  0.98         Group 1
    Product 8                                  0.98         Group 1

    --- Group Footer ---
```

Any ideas why Access insists on creating a group footer when the field I'm grouping on hasn't changed?

Because products in group 1 have varying prices, I can't group first and sort second.  The priority is to sort on UnitPrice.

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. I have a stripped-down .accdb example but I don't seem to be able to attach it to this post, if anyone would like to see it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, You should really post that example, even though you can't attach files directly. You can copy and paste the code as a code example. It is hard to be helpful without knowing what you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, Access reports aren't code so I can't post them.

Comment: In your report, what are you actually trying to group on? I don't see anything in your required result to show what you're grouping on. Right now it appears to be grouping on price, and since the prices in the first group vary, it's giving you each individually. But your third column has two sets of 'Group 1'. Is that a typo? If not, you don't have anything unique to group on. Are you trying to group by price range?

Comment: I want to group on the field I'm calling "Group".  That's the problem - Access is creating extra group footers when the value for Group hasn't changed.

Comment: I'd need to see more about your database and how you're setting up your form. I know you don't have enough reputation to be able to put your data on stack overflow, but maybe you could download it to dropbox or something equivalent and post a link. It should be possible to help you figure this out if I can see it.

Comment: Thanks Lynne!  I should have thought of using Dropbox.  Here's the link:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/67t7xkxwzgyoyl0/SortGroupTest.zip?dl=0